# Adding a Scrollable in a Stack Material UI

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, material-ui

I have created a component and I need to make it scrollable when it gets too big to the right

```
  <Stack direction="row">
      <Stack gap={1} overflow="auto">
        {fields.map((el, i) => (
          <TableInputArray
            key={el.id}
            control={control}
            register={register}
            tableIndex={i}
            columnCount={columnCount}
          />
        ))}
    </Stack>
</Stack>
```

I have no idea how to add that scroll to the right in the Material UI

Answer (score 0):

You should apply the "overflowX: 'auto'" style to the 'sx' prop of the Stack component.

```
<Stack direction="row" sx={{ overflowX: 'auto' }}>
  <Stack gap={1}>
    {fields.map((el, i) => (
      <TableInputArray
        key={el.id}
        control={control}
        register={register}
        tableIndex={i}
        columnCount={columnCount}
      />
    ))}
  </Stack>
</Stack>
```